# Can't upgrade using a liveUSB, through the newer version is recognized

Tags: upgrade, live-usb

I run a 13.04 on one of my laptops, now someone brought me the 13.10 iso image (I work in rural Africa), yet upgrading to 13.10 didn't work:

1. I created a liveUSB
2. I rebooted from it
3. Chose "Install 13.10"
4. I could see the option "upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10", but couldn't select it.

Parallel-installation is not an option, to be frank. Any ideas?